# My SFML (in CodeBlocks) doesn't work

Tags: c++, sfml

i've got a problem with this code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when i try to run it CodeBlocks say:

```
undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)
undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)
```

And a lot of other error. Here the library include

[image]

And i define "SFML_STATIC" too.
Do anyone know why? thanks.

Comment: Can you post the "lot of other errors"? One might explain *why* you get those errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting from SFML 2.2, when static linking, you will have to link all
> of SFML's dependencies to your project as well. This means that if you
> are linking sfml-window-s or sfml-window-s-d for example, you will
> also have to link opengl32, winmm and gdi32. Some of these dependency
> libraries might already be listed under "Inherited values", but adding
> them again yourself shouldn't cause any problems.
>
> Additionally,  because Code::Blocks makes use of GCC, the linking order does matter.
> This means that libraries that depend on other libraries have to be
> added to the library list before the libraries they depend on. If you
> don't follow this rule, you will get linker errors.

You can see here the the dependencies of each module

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-cb.php

hope this helps.